# Calling TestCase class cause functions to run twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I was trying to dynamically create test functions when I notice a weird behavior that I do not understand. I have reduced the code to this for simple understanding. I am running it on python 3.6.7

Code:

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print('SET UP')

    def test_x(self):
        print('hi')

x = MyTestCase # <-This causes the test function to run twice, Why???

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('test start')
    unittest.main()
    print('test end') # <- This does not get printed
```

Output:

```
test start
SET UP
hi
.hi
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

As you can see, the test function test_x is being run twice and the last print statement is not executed

So my questions are:

1. why does the test function run twice?
2. why is the print statement print('test end') not executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1. why does the test function run twice?*

Because the `unittest` code finds *two* objects in the module's namespace that are `unittest.TestCase` classes, `MyTestCase` and `x`.  It doesn't check that these are actually the *same* object.  (Well, it has *some* awareness of this, in that it doesn't treat `x` as a new class to be tested, so it doesn't call `setUpClass` again; see ["Class and Module Fixtures"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures).)

*2. why is the print statement print('test end') not executed?*

By default, `unittest.main()` calls `sys.exit()` after running the tests.  You can disable this by adding the argument `exit=False`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('test start')
    unittest.main(exit=False)
    print('test end')
```